# How can I send the request to TargetingIdeaService web service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, wsdl, google-ads-api

I'm working on .net application, I need to get some information of keywords like Search Volume or Average CPC ... I've added this web service to my application
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201309/TargetingIdeaService?wsdl (link to TargetingIdeaService)

And I wrote the following code, but I'm lost, I don't know how to send the request and how to get the result of my query ... The ( AdwordsService ) is the name of the web service .

```
    Dim Keywords(2) As String
    Keywords(0) = "Domain Tester"
    Keywords(1) = "Domain Appraisal"

    Dim Selector As New AdwordsService.TargetingIdeaSelector()
    Selector.requestType = AdwordsService.RequestType.IDEAS
    Selector.ideaType = AdwordsService.IdeaType.KEYWORD

    Dim Ar(4) As AdwordsService.AttributeType
    Ar(0) = AdwordsService.AttributeType.KEYWORD_TEXT
    Ar(1) = AdwordsService.AttributeType.COMPETITION
    Ar(2) = AdwordsService.AttributeType.SEARCH_VOLUME
    Ar(3) = AdwordsService.AttributeType.AVERAGE_CPC
    Selector.requestedAttributeTypes = Ar

    Dim LangageParam = New AdwordsService.LanguageSearchParameter()
    Dim English = New AdwordsService.Language()
    English.id = 1000
    Dim LangArray(1) As AdwordsService.Language
    LangArray(0) = English
    LangageParam.languages = LangArray

    Dim relatedToQuerySearchParameter As New AdwordsService.RelatedToQuerySearchParameter()
    relatedToQuerySearchParameter.queries = Keywords
    Dim searchParameters(2) As AdwordsService.SearchParameter
    searchParameters(0) = relatedToQuerySearchParameter
    searchParameters(1) = LangageParam
    Selector.searchParameters = searchParameters
    Selector.paging = New AdwordsService.Paging()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you don't know how to call the service, then what led you to write all that code? Did you see an example? See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)".